# Scala - How to use filter on Map

Tags: scala

If I have map with filename and it's size and I want to filter it based on it's size, I can do something like this.

```
val fileCount = Map("a.txt"->10, "b.txt"->0)
```

**First Way**

```
val zeroSizeFiles = fileCount.filter(t=>t._2 != 0)
```

or

```
val zeroSizeFiles = fileCount.filter(_._2 != 0)
```

I realized that, I can do something like this, which is more verbose

**Second Way**

```
val zeroSizeFiles = fileCount.filter{case(fileName, count) => count == 0}
```

So, is there any disadvantage in using second way as compared to first or advantage apart from being more readabel?

Comment: No, they are all three equivalent. One can argue that the second way may be a little bit more slow, due the extra call to unapply on the pattern matching, but usually that can be ignored. Note that, for the second way I would  write it like this: `filter { case (_, count) => count == 0 }`  _(Note the spaces and the underscore `_` to ignore the first component of the tuple)_.